# Including an include function inside of a variable

Tags: php, html, include

I want to include a file in 
$includes[content] is  a variable and i want to use an include function.

```
$includes[content]="
<form action=\"index.php?view=login&action=login&".iif($rid!="","rid=$rid&")."".$url_variables."\" method=\"post\" onSubmit=\"submitonce(this)\">
<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$returnTo\" name=\"returnTo\">
Some html in php form.
 <-- I want to add include 'sys/CodeGen.php'; function -->
Some more html in php form.

Ends in
</form></div>

";
?>
```

How do i add  in between the includes[content] ?

Comment: Don't do it. Don't define HTML in function.

Comment: $includes[content]="
<font color=\"darkred\">$msg</font>
<div align=\"center\">
some more
</form></div>

";
?>
Where $msg does not appear.. it's blank appearing.. it dosen't matter for now.

It is just a variable that is being defined to be included in the end for result

Comment: Don't do it. Don't define HTML in a variable. **Use templates**

Comment: ok thanks..i think that'll be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question. I'm assuming you want to do something like this:

```
$variable = "some html";
include($variable);
```

If that's the case, all I can say is "you can't, and you shouldn't".

The "can't" part of that is because the `include()` function (and its brethren) use the value passed to them to look up a file and read it. If it's passed anything other than the path to a file, it fails. This is a good thing.

What you want to do is create a template file that you can include where you need it. For example:

```
// form.inc    
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>">
<input type="hidden" value="$returnTo" name="returnTo">
</form>
```

It's a lot cleaner to do it that way than it is to try to throw it in a variable.

If you're going to be calling that template a lot, and you're worried about performance (which is really the only thing I can think of to rationalize this), then you can write a function in your template, then `include_once` the file.

For example:

```
// form.inc

<?php
  function writeForm($action) {
?>
    <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" value="$returnTo" name="returnTo">
    </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

This way, you can call `include_once("form.inc");` and when PHP parses the file, it will create a function called `writeForm()` that you can call as often as you like, without having to read from disk every time.

If you have a bunch of tiny snippets of code you want to include, but don't want to have a bunch of three-line files hanging around (again, for whatever reason), then you could always have a "snippets.inc" file which defines all of these little functions as I've outlined above.

You could even take it one further and group related snippets together and create a Helper class.